# How to find user-agent of device/tablet in windows phone and windows 8.1 using c#?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, user-agent

I want to find **UserAgent** of device running my app using c#. Can anyone suggest how to find that using some code. I did some research and most of them are showing hard coded string or implementation using java-script. But i want to find it using c#. Please someone suggest a quick and easy solution.

Comment: instead of down voting my question, you correct it or give an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code requires adding a webBrowser control to a page,

```
public partial class HomeView : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public HomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += HomeView_Loaded;
    }

    private void HomeView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserAgentHelper.GetUserAgent(
            LayoutRoot,
            userAgent =>
                {
                // TODO: Store this wherever you want
                ApplicationSettings.Current.UserAgent = userAgent;
               });
    }
}
```

The Helper

```
public static class UserAgentHelper
{
private const string Html =
    @"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"">

    <html>
    <head>
    <script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">
        function notifyUA() {
            window.external.notify(navigator.userAgent);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=""notifyUA();""></body>
    </html>";

public static void GetUserAgent(Panel rootElement, Action<string> callback)
{
    var browser = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser();
    browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    browser.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    browser.Loaded += (sender, args) => browser.NavigateToString(Html);
    browser.ScriptNotify += (sender, args) =>
                                {
                                    string userAgent = args.Value;
                                    rootElement.Children.Remove(browser);
                                    callback(userAgent);
                                };
    rootElement.Children.Add(browser);
}
}
```

Comment: `System.Web` is not available for Windows 8.1 so this will not work without it :-(

Comment: This works fine in Windows Phone 8 but not in Windows 8.1. I tried to change WebBrowser control to WebView but it didn't worked.

Comment: user-agent string was change in latest version of windows OS. you can follow these url for more details. [link1](http://wmpoweruser.com/wp8-1-update-1s-ie-user-agent-pretends-to-be-android-4-0-and-ios-7-good-enough-to-fool-gmail/) and [link2](http://www.neowin.net/news/ie11-fakes-user-agent-to-fool-gmail-in-windows-phone-81-gdr1-update)

Comment: If you want to get user agent in windows 8.1, you can return javascript value in C#.

Comment: @Mudakkhir thanks, can you share some code for returning javascript value in c#?

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertScript", "function returnString() {  return navigator.userAgent; } document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = returnString();", true);`
           `string UserAgent = HiddenField1.Value;`

Comment: `ScriptManager` comes under which library, I am getting error that `ScriptManger doesn't exist in current context`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83827/discussion-between-musakkhir-sayyed-and-kinjan-bhavsar).